# FQL :Compare facebook pages Daily Likes, Comments, and Shares

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I like to know how to use FQL to count daily likes, comments and shares
I try this but Its not working.. I need help

```
$fql  = "SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id in 
   (SELECT target_id FROM connection WHERE source_id=153615111448758 AND is_following=1) AND is_hidden = 0";

$apifql="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=".urlencode($fql);

$json=file_get_contents($apifql);


print_r( json_decode($json));
```

Comment: How is it not working? Did you get empty json or any error message at all?

Comment: Why are you using the deprecated endpoint? Use https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=...